# SPARQL dbpedia select data not working

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I'm new to sparql and I'm learning it right now.
I took this code from a tutorial

```
prefix dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
prefix dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

select distinct ?Predicate ?Object where {
  ?Subject ?Predicate ?Object  
  filter(?Subject = dbpr:Markiplier)
}
```

and executed it on http://dbpedia.org/sparql, it returns empty result 
as you can see on this image
[image]

I tried many codes and I always get empty result, is there anything I must do to get data ? Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: That query returns results, I don't know what you're doing ...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why you put space for publishing the question but you should reunite them again. Besides you can also ask for ?Subjectif you like:

```
prefix dbpo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
prefix dbpr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>

select distinct ?Subject ?Predicate ?Object where {
  ?Subject ?Predicate ?Object  
  filter(?Subject = dbpr:Markiplier)
}
```

By the way if you have troubles with prefixes, I would reccomend to work on the http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ endpoint. So that you can use the predefined prefixes directly like [this](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%0D%0Aselect%20distinct%20%3FPredicate%20%3FObject%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3FSubject%20%3FPredicate%20%3FObject%20%20%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%3FSubject%20%3D%20%3AMarkiplier%29%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: thanks for your replay, i'm new to stack-overflow so i can't publish question with many links. so that i add space.
can i add query to search about sport on http://dbpedia.org/page/Syria with http://dbpedia.org/snorql/ endpoint ?

Comment: @Nour What is "sport on Syria"? In general, you can only query for data that exists in DBpedia.

Comment: As @AKSW said you can search for the data that exist in DBpedia. There is a triple with "dbr:Sport_in_Syria", do you mean that?

Comment: @user730611 yes i mean this "dbr:Sport_in_Syria", what is the right query to search about that triple ?

Comment: What would you like to search about that triple? Should you add it to the query above? Maybe it is another question..Probably you would like to search for this category: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Sport_in_Syria..Please take a look at that resource.